# calculate average session duration depending on its number (duration of the first session, the second and so on)

Tags: sql, database, data-analysis

| id | session | server_time | event | level | event_duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | h45jdnvj | 2022-02-05 12:01:31 | level_started | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | h45jdnvj | 2022-02-05 12:01:36 | level_completed | 1 | 36 |
| 1 | h45jdnvj | 2022-02-05 12:02:06 | level_started | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | h45jdnvj | 2022-02-05 12:02:36 | level_completed | 2 | 32 |
| 2 | CM0yORn5 | 2022-02-12 14:45:01 | level_started | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | CM0yORn5 | 2022-02-12 14:45:26 | level_completed | 3 | 70 |
| 1 | SIDw6sZf | 2022-02-05 11:03:23 | level_started | 31 | 0 |
| 1 | SIDw6sZf | 2022-02-05 11:04:04 | level_completed | 31 | 41 |
| 2 | fzoojoaR | 2022-02-05 11:09:19 | level_started | 32 | 0 |
| 2 | fzoojoaR | 2022-02-05 11:09:29 | level_failed | 32 | 11 |
| 2 | fzoojoaR | 2022-02-05 11:09:50 | level_started | 32 | 0 |
| 2 | fzoojoaR | 2022-02-05 11:10:45 | level_completed | 32 | 55 |
| 2 | fzoojoaR | 2022-02-05 11:11:40 | level_started | 33 | 0 |

A user can have many sessions.
WITHOUT WINDOW FUNCTION
event_duration - this is the duration of the event in seconds

I'm new to sql and can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Hi @alesya, how will you define session duration here? last event server time - first event server time? or sum(all event durations)?

Comment: hi, session duration is last event server time - first event server time

Comment: Got it, could you further specify which DB engine you use?

Comment: I use clickhouse and it does not support window functions

Comment: Alright, I write a answer on per user per session duration based on defintion you describe, see whether that is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use window function, you can use [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator, [min(), max()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) function and [date_diff()](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/date-time-functions/) function in clickhouse to get the result you need.

We use a trick to calculate session_order_num by couting how many session starts before current session.

Here is the query(without window function):

```
WITH session_duration AS (
SELECT
    id,
    session,
    MIN(server_time) as session_start_time,
    date_diff('second', MIN(server_time), MAX(server_time)) as session_duration
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    id,
    session
),
session_duration_with_order AS (
SELECT
    s_current.id,
    s_current.session,
    s_current.session_duration,
    SUM(CASE WHEN s_current.session_start_time > s_previous.session_start_time THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+1 as session_order_num
FROM session_duration s_current
JOIN
    session_duration s_previous
ON
    s_current.id = s_previous.id    
GROUP BY
    s_current.id,
    s_current.session,
    s_current.session_duration
    
)
SELECT
    session_order_num,
    AVG(session_duration) AS avg_session_duration
FROM
    session_duration_with_order
GROUP BY
    session_order_num
ORDER BY
    session_order_num
```

| session_order_num | avg_session_duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 91 |
| 2 | 45 |

ClickHouse document indeed specifies it [supports window function](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/).

Here is the query(with window function):

```
WITH session_duration AS (
SELECT
    id,
    session,
    MIN(server_time) as session_start_time,
    date_diff('second', MIN(server_time), MAX(server_time)) as session_duration
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    id,
    session
),
session_duration_with_order AS (
SELECT
    id,
    session,
    session_duration,
    row_number() over (partition by id order by session_start_time) as session_order_num
    FROM session_duration    
)
SELECT
    session_order_num,
    AVG(session_duration)
FROM
    session_duration_with_order
GROUP BY
    session_order_num
ORDER BY
    session_order_num
```

| session_order_num | avg_session_duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 91 |
| 2 | 45 |

Comment: meant to display the average value of the first, second, third and so on sessions for all id

Comment: Hi @alesya, to clarify, if 1st session duration is 10 sec, 2nd session duration is 20 sec,3rd session duration is 30 sec, then average session duration for 1st session is 10/1 = 10 sec, average session duration for 2nd session is (10+20) /2 = 15 sec, average session duration for 3rd session is (10+20+30) / 3 = 20 sec. Is this what you expect?

Comment: for example, the duration of the first session of the first user is 10 seconds, the second user is 15 seconds. Then the average duration of the first session for these users is 10+15/2 = 12.5

Comment: error: Unsupported JOIN ON conditions. Unexpected 'session_start_time > s_previous.session_start_time': While processing session_start_time > s_previous.session_start_time. (INVALID_JOIN_ON_EXPRESSION)

Comment: Hi @alesya, thanks for the clarifications, just finished updating the query and testing it with the new requirement, please have a try to see whether it works for you.

Comment: I have a much larger database and writes an error: SQL Error [159] [07000]: Read timed out

Comment: Hi @alesya, you do need to use window function to better performance in this case, based on clickhouse document, it does support window function. You may need to further check what is blocking you from using window function then. "ClickHouse supports the standard grammar for defining windows and window functions. The following features are currently supported:" https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/

Comment: and where to apply?

Comment: HI @alesya, I add the last section in the answer with query using window function, if you still can't use it, check clickhouse window function document to see where exactly it is blocking you from using window function. https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/window-functions/

Comment: Awesome, that's great to hear.